# cacheDirectory deprecated in 0.13...so now what?

Tags: caching, task, sbt, updates

Asked this on the sbt mailing list, but apparently it is being [phased out](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/JWh5bSUrnck)

I created a [project on github](https://github.com/godenji/play-faster) that works around "sbt> clean" from blowing away artifact update cache directory.
Works great on 0.12.4, but broken in 0.13, my custom update cache directory is empty after "sbt> update"

What's the equivalent of:

```
cacheDirectory <<= baseDirectory / "sbt-no-clean"
```

in 0.13? I see that `cacheDirectory` has been deprecated and that we are to use `streams` instead.

The [SBT FAQ](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/faq.html) for 0.13 has a section on using FileFunction.cached, is that the replacement for above 1 liner? Doesn't look like it.

Streams may indeed do the job, but since old method of working with `cacheDirectory` no longer works -- well, technically the attribute is set, but something overrides it, so it's more of a removal than deprecation functionality-wise -- I have shifted gears and am trying to use `cleanKeepFiles`:

```
cleanKeepFiles <<= (streams) map{s=> Seq(s.cacheDirectory)}
```

I get a return type mismatch, a maddening one at that, as I have no idea how to turn:

```
sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]]
```

into

```
sbt.Def.Initialize[Seq[java.io.File]]
```

Ideas appreciated,
Thanks

**EDIT**
If you use apply instead of map:

```
cleanKeepFiles <<= streams.apply{_.map(x=>Seq(x.cacheDirectory))}
```

then you get:

```
sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]
```

which seems to be getting closer, but then the compiler wants:

```
Seq[java.io.File]
```

`cleanKeepFiles` is of type `SettingKey[Seq[File]]`

I am beyond confused as to how to get a `SettingKey[Seq[File]]` out of stream's type: `TaskKey[TaskStreams]`

Comment: If you use the new 0.13 syntax like `set cleanKeepFiles := Seq(streams.value.cacheDirectory)` then the error message is unequivocal: `error: A setting cannot depend on a task` which seems to indicate that it's not just a matter of fiddling until the types line up. Hopefully someone else has further insight.

Comment: @SethTisue I did come up with a solution, but forgot I posted this question on SO ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally forgot about posting this question, solution was thankfully pretty simple:

```
cleanKeepFiles <+= base / pathToCacheDir
```

That prevents SBT from blowing away deps cache on every single clean, which shaves a few seconds off clean/compile cycles -- a nice & easy WIN, just like we were able to do with cacheDirectory in SBT <= 0.12.4

Comment: Did you mean `cleanKeepFiles <+= target / "streams"` (and "resolution-cache")? Seems to be working for me in `build.sbt`. ...now the question is to figure out how to apply this to sub-projects without copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing `cacheDirectory` to `target` worked in my case:

from:

```
cacheDirectory <<= baseDirectory / "sbt-no-clean"
```

to

```
target <<= baseDirectory / "sbt-no-clean"
```